# Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-4.2'

Tags: centos, installation, mongodb

I'm try install mongoDb community version by this link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

The step one it's ok: 
1)Configure the package management system (yum).

But in the step two, the error occurs:
2)Install the MongoDB packages.

I get the following message:
*Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-4.2'*

Comment: What specific version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: Hi @Stennie, I'm using RHEL 8/CentOS 8